# Scripting a file move on an FTP Server

Tags: bash, scripting, ftp

I'm attempting to move multiple files on an FTP server to a different directory on the same server. So far, I've written a bash script that will login and retrieve any new files in the remote directory but the ftp command doesn't support a 'mv' command. Essentially the script would download the new file(s) and then once downloaded move the file(s) to a different directory on the same server.  Please Note that the filenames will be different every time so the use of wildcards is important here.

Before you answer please note that this needs to be automated so using a GUI like Filezilla wouldn't help me as I would have to login to various ftp sites and move the files manually, also, keep in mind that I'm unable to ssh into any of the servers as they are managed by other company's and ftp access is all I'm able to get. Last thing, I won't know what the file names are so using a wildcard would be helpful.

Any help or guidance is truly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the **rename** command in ftp could work for you?

```
rename [from [to]]
       Rename the file from on the remote machine, to the file to.
```

I gave it a bash with an old file I had sitting on a server and it seemed to do what you want:

```
ftp> ls tmp/test*
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||55572|)
150 Accepted data connection
-rw-r--r--    1 sinasohn   sinasohn           21 Mar 31 16:37 tmp/testfile01
226-Options: -a -l 
226 1 matches total

ftp> ls tmp2/test*
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||64715|)
150 Accepted data connection
226-Options: -a -l 
226 0 matches total

ftp> rename tmp/testfile01 tmp2/testfile01
350 RNFR accepted - file exists, ready for destination
250 File successfully renamed or moved

ftp> ls tmp/test*
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||56698|)
150 Accepted data connection
226-Options: -a -l 
226 0 matches total

ftp> ls tmp2/test*
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50239|)
150 Accepted data connection
-rw-r--r--    1 sinasohn   sinasohn           21 Mar 31 16:37 tmp2/testfile01
226-Options: -a -l 
226 1 matches total
ftp>
```

I put blank lines in between commands here for clarity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I've tried this though the rename command doesn't support wildcards and so I need a way to do this with wildcards even if it means having a separate script to perform just the task of moving files within ftp.  Thanks Again!

Comment: The **ls** command in ftp allows you to specify a local file name for output.  Could you do an _ls * filelist.txt_ and then parse that file to get the list of files to use in rename statements?

Comment: How could I parse the filelist.txt?  Do you have an example?

Comment: You can use this: `cat filelist.txt | awk '{print $9}'` to get just the file name.  (Note: you'll need to skip the first two lines as they'll be "**.**" and "**..**".)  From that, you can build your **rename** commands.

Comment: This will skip the first two lines (the "**.**" and "**..**"):  `cat filelist.txt | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n +3 `.

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try.  Thank you for the suggestion!  I will provide feedback shortly.

Comment: This will generate a file with rename statements in it that you can feed to ftp: `cat filelist.txt | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n +3 | sed -r "s/^(.*)$/rename \1 ..\/test2\/\1/g" >fileren.txt`  Note that the slashes ("/") in the path need to be escaped with a backslash ("\") to avoid conflict with the slashes that are part of the sed command.  (I believe you can use other delimiters, but I'm too lazy to look up what they are.  Sorry.)

Comment: Cool this worked to list out the files to a list Thank you for that!  Now how can I run the ftp command and use the list to rename the files?

Comment: If your file has the rename commands in it, you can simply feed that to ftp: `ftp username@hostname < fileren.txt`.  Note that your version of ftp may have the `-s` option so you could say `ftp -s:fileren.txt username@hostname`.

Answer (score 0):

full script to achieve move more than one file 
1. get file list from ftp server with mls command 
2. generate to do list file 
   2.1 get file 
   2.2 rename (move file) 
3. execute ftp command with to do list file

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
# change local directory
cd [local-directory]

#collect file names
ftp -ni ftp.abccompany.com <<EOF
user [user] [password]
cd /OUT
mls abc*.* list.txt 
quit
EOF

# create ftp action list
echo >>todo.lst user [user] [password]
while read N
do
    echo >>todo.lst cd /OUT
    echo >>todo.lst get $N
    echo >>todo.lst rename $N ARCHIVE/$N
done <list.txt

echo >>todo.lst quit

# ftp transfer process
ftp -nv ftp.abccompany.com <todo.lst

# cleanup
rm todo.lst
```